# TIME Format Issue in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When i am posting date and time .. the date is Okay but the time appeared Like this

: Thu Jan 01 1970 12:59:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)

And when i checked the DB it was :

[In DB ( Time Not the same Because of the Eastern European Standard Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4ivC.png)

Comment: Please provide more information. What is your problem here? The timezone? the formatting?

Comment: The Problem is : The Posted Time is not the one that saved in DB.

Comment: Yeah I got that. What’s the posted time in the DB?

Comment: The One in the Picture is the DB.
and the posted one is : Thu Jan 01 1970 12:59:00

The Posted = 12:59:00
In DB = 10:59:00

Comment: That _is_ the same time. Notice the +0200 at the end of the posted one. In your database the time is in UTC (+0000 or Z), in your frontend it’s got the timezone offset.

Comment: Thanks .. i got it